# Bootstrap context menu Dropdown in table with tbody tr onclick event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I use Bootstrap 3 and KnockoutJS.

I have a table with 5 columns and want to add a 6th column for context-menu actions, using Bootstrap Dropdown.

Here is my html:

```
<table id="employeesTable" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover myDefaultTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="myDefaultTable-left">Employee Name</th>
            <th>... 4 other columns</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Employee">
        <tr data-bind="attr: { 'id': EmployeeId }">
            <td class="myDefaultTable-left" data-bind="text: EmployeeName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: col2"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: col3"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: col4"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: col5"></td>
            <td>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Actions
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.RemoveEmployee.bind($parent), clickBubble: false">Remove employee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.DuplicateEmployee.bind($parent), clickBubble: false">Duplicate employee</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is that in JavaScript, I have (and want to keep) a click action that opens up a detail screen for the clicked item in the table, as follows:

```
$container.on('click', '#employeesTable tbody tr', { self: self }, self._employeeDetailClick);
```

My context-menu events are exposed as follows:

```
self._model = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
self._model.self = self;
self._model.RemoveEmployee = self._removeEmployee;
```

I am looking for a way to not call the "`tbody tr` on click event" when the user clicks on column 6 but to call the appropriate context-menu event.  I tried `clickBubble: false` but it's not working.

If I comment-out the line

```
$container.on('click', '#employeesTable tbody tr', { self: self }, self._employeeDetailClick);
```

...then my context-menu works.

Comment: Could you edit the post and add//remove some code to make it into an [mcve]? Some of the post is hard to follow because of missing and/or possibly irrelevant bits.

Comment: On a general note, with Knockout you typically have either a `click` binding handler or a custom binding handler for integration with DOM-manipulating widgets. Did you try to use either?

Comment: I have removed the jQuery event handling and implemented a Knockout click binding on the first 5 columns of the table.  That solved my issue.  Thank you @Jeroen and user3297291 for leading me in such direction.  It is indeed much clearer.

Comment: Good to hear. Don't forget to either accept an appropriate answer, or share your own solution as an answer, so others with the same issue can easily spot the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`clickBubble: false` actually prevents the click event from bubbling up to the DOM element's parents. You'll need to set it to `true`.

Other than that, I strongly agree with Jeroen: you should avoid mixing up jQuery & knockout event handling.

```js
var log = function(library) { console.log(library + ": CLICK") };

ko.applyBindings({
  logClick: log.bind(null, "KO")
});

$("body").click(log.bind(null, "jQuery"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: logClick, clickBubble: true">click bubble true</button>

<button data-bind="click: logClick, clickBubble: false">click bubble false</button>
```